# Unable to use OfflineIMAP to sync Gmail

Tags: email, offlineimap

I'm trying to setup OfflineIMAP to sync my Gmail account to `~/Mail/Gmail`. I'm using a pretty basic `~/.offlineimaprc` from [here](http://pbrisbin.com/posts/mutt_gmail_offlineimap). But OfflineIMAP doesn't connect to Gmail at all. This is the debug message I'm getting (by running OfflineIMAP as `offlineimap -o -d imap`:

```
OfflineIMAP 6.3.4
Copyright 2002-2011 John Goerzen & contributors.
Licensed under the GNU GPL v2+ (v2 or any later version).

Debug mode: Forcing to singlethreaded.
Now debugging for imap: IMAP protocol debugging
Now debugging for : Other offlineimap related sync messages
Account sync Gmail:
***** Processing account Gmail
Copying folder structure from IMAP to Maildir
Establishing connection to imap.gmail.com:993.
DEBUG[imap]:   06:28.69 Account sync Gmail imaplib2 version 2.24
DEBUG[imap]:   06:28.69 Account sync Gmail imaplib2 debug level 5, buffer level 3
WARNING: Error occured attempting to sync account 'Gmail':
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 177, in syncrunner
    self.sync()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 235, in sync
    remoterepos.syncfoldersto(localrepos, [statusrepos])
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/offlineimap/repository/Base.py", line 124, in syncfoldersto
    srcfolders = src.getfolders()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/offlineimap/repository/IMAP.py", line 276, in getfolders
    imapobj = self.imapserver.acquireconnection()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 323, in acquireconnection
    elif isinstance(e, socket.error) and e.args[0] == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
NameError: global name 'errno' is not defined

***** Finished processing account Gmail
```

In the beginning I thought this could be due to my ISP blocking `imap.gmail.com/imap.googlemail.com`, but I'm able to connect to it using `telnet imap.googlemail.com 993`:

```
telnet imap.googlemail.com 993
Trying 173.194.79.16...
Connected to googlemail-imap.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:** From this answer on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/346962), I tried connecting to `imap.googlemail.com` via SSL using `openssl s_client -connect imap.googlemail.com:993`. This gives me:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
3078125768:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 226 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

This looks like a missing certificate problem in OpenSSL. Could the same be happening to OfflineIMAP too?

**EDIT 2:** I tried the same OpenSSL commands on another server (on the same network) running Mandriva Linux release 2009.1 and apparently the connection worked ([debug output](http://sprunge.us/XNFM)). I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenSSL/LibSSL 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.5. Could this be distro related?

Comment: It may help to post your offlineimap version, as that project has quite a few versions in the wild and some of them are badly broken.  Try also their mailing list, whose info you can find on [their home page](http://offlineimap.org/).

Answer (score 12):

Instead of manually specifying the fingerprint (which can change), you can instead tell offlineimap where your local system certificates are stored and then have it automatically verify the chain.

```
[Repository somerepos-remote]
type = Gmail
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

The sslcacertfile is what does the trick.

If non-Ubuntu users are seeing this, keep in mind that the location is most likely different on your distro.

Comment: any idea where the ``sslcacertfile`` path on OSX?

Comment: @Meitham looks like`sslcacertfile = /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` according to http://rudolfochrist.github.io/blog/2015/03/21/offlineimap-with-ssl-files-on-osx/.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following line to the section in .offlineimaprc describing your remote Gmail account:

```
cert_fingerprint=f3043dd689a2e7dddfbef82703a6c65ea9b634c1
```

This is the SSL cert of Gmail's imap server.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not OpenSSL missing a certificate it's a SSL handshake failure because the other end did not send its certificate.

You would get a similar error when you connect to some non-SSL enabled service.

What do you get when you add the -debug option to openssl?

answer:

```
read from 0x9cd8b98 [0x9cde140] (7 bytes => 0 (0x0))
```

So it read nothing from the socket (suggesting it was closed by the other end or something in between before sending anything)

Is there some sort of proxy on your network? Some sort of iptables redirection or antivirus on the local machine?

What does `tshark -Vi any port 993` give you when you try the openssl command?

Comment: Thanks! [Here's](http://sprunge.us/AINF) the result of running OpenSSL with the `-debug` option. Apparently I am able to connect from another server on the same network. I am now thinking that this could be distro specific. I've updated my question as well.